# Can you change text url to link button

Tags: feature-request, post-ban

I saw this below message on some page

> We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more

But `http://goo.gl/C1Kwu` is a just text. Stack Overflow is a big professional site, so can you change this text to URL (link button style) or this format below?

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) to learn more.

Comment: Part of the punishment, I think.